# Why isn't this line chart drawing? (d3js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

The data comes in a format like this:

```
[
    {y: 17.0, x: '2015-07-23 00:02:41'}, 
    {y: 17.0, x: '2015-07-23 00:03:41'}, 
    {y: 15.0, x: '2015-07-23 01:21:44'}, 
    {y: 23.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:50:48'}, 
    {y: 21.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:51:48'}, 
    {y: 28.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:52:48'}, 
    {y: 24.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:53:48'}, 
    {y: 27.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:54:48'}, 
    {y: 18.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:55:48'}, 
    {y: 28.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:56:48'}
]
```

I'm trying to draw a line chart based on that data; but every time I try it's blank; this is what I'm doing:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height,0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var vline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(parseDate(d.x)); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d.y); });

// add canvas
var svg = d3.select(".swatch").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);

// draw line
svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", vline(data));

// x axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// y axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
```

The fields output properly when printed with `console.log` (from `var vline = d3.svg.line()...` but the line is never drawn.

Any idea why it's not drawing the line?

Comment: The structure of data is [{x:<time>, y:1}], to generate line you are passing x(parseDate(d.x)), In parseDate the format is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S". Is your data in Year-Month-Date Hour:Minutes:Seconds this format?? and x domain you are setting d.x not with parseDate(d.x)???

Comment: The mistake is x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; })); in this you are returning d.x, but where as vline parseDate(d.x), so use same in both places, otherwise path data is malformed, NaN is coming for x. Mind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 data =[
    {y: 17.0, x: '2015-07-23 00:02:41'}, 
    {y: 17.0, x: '2015-07-23 00:03:41'}, 
    {y: 15.0, x: '2015-07-23 01:21:44'}, 
    {y: 23.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:50:48'}, 
    {y: 21.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:51:48'}, 
    {y: 28.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:52:48'}, 
    {y: 24.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:53:48'}, 
    {y: 27.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:54:48'}, 
    {y: 18.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:55:48'}, 
    {y: 28.0, x: '2015-07-23 02:56:48'}
];
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height,0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var vline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(parseDate(d.x)); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d.y); });

// add canvas
var svg = d3.select(".swatch").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseDate(d.x); }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })]);

// draw line
svg.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", vline(data));

// x axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// y axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);
    });
```

```css
path {
 stroke: black;
 fill: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="dectree" class='swatch'></div>
```

Here is working.....

Comment: Let me add to that: the style for the path  (fill:none) is important, otherwise your open path gets closed by default and filled with black.